# What would you call a list of parts in a single word

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

What is a single word to describe a list of parts, tools, and instructions to be assembled later to form an object.
Examples:
Bag of parts/tools/instructions for a DIY crib
A group of parameters to be sent as an object with both properties and methods to describe how to build out the object *(software-factory pattern,IOC)*
List of car parts/schematics/assembly instructions to be assembled in the factory.

To clarify, I am looking for a general term that could apply to any or all of the scenarios above.

Comment: "Parts"..................

Comment: 1) Parts/Materials 2) Parameters (that's literally the term) 3) Parts...?

Comment: Supplies? Formal parameters. Automobile components.

Comment: Are you just talking about the list of parts, rather than the complete instructions? For instance if you’ve seen a Lego or Ikea instruction booklet, are you referring to the inventory they provide at the beginning?

Comment: @user77595 yes, like the Lego boxes, parts and/or assembly instructions.

Comment: I'm guessing that if there were a single word that meant that one would see it on the sheet of paper that often comes with a tool or appliance, instead of the title "Parts List".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Inventory* or *parts list*.

Software is the odd one out here, as parameters are really just *parameters*, and a list of parameters is called just that, a *list of parameters*.

Comment: An inventory is **not** a parts list. Some inventories are parts lists.  An inventory of **parts** is a parts list. The answer is *parts list*, if two words are OK. If not, @Oldcat had it right: the answer is that the list is called *Parts*.

Comment: Although I do agree that inventory may not properly define exactly what I was asking for, it worked well enough for my situation to use. PartsList would not work in this case as it is not *just* a pile of parts but also the tools and instructions required by a third party to assemble. I really should clarify that I was looking for more than just the parts... I'll do that now. But thank you for your comment because it does help me to see where I left holes in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Repertoire : a list of parts or list of acts to be performed.